# load icons in a Qlistwidget and set the text for each icon with the filename of the icon

Tags: icons, load, qlistwidget

I have a folder with icons an I want to load them in a Qlistwidget in icon mode  and set the text for each icon  with the filename of each icon

I figure out this code and it works but is there a better or faster way to do the same thing

```
  void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
   {
  QDir dir ("....");
  dir.setSorting(QDir::Name);
  QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::AllEntries | 
  QDir::Dirs|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

  for(int i=0 ; i < list.length() ; i++)
  {
   QIcon icon;
   icon.addFile(list.at(i).absoluteFilePath(), 
               QSize(), 
               QIcon::Normal,
               QIcon::Off);
 QListWidgetItem *qlistwidgetitem = new QListWidgetItem(ui->listWidget);
 qlistwidgetitem->setIcon(icon);
 QListWidgetItem *_qlistwidgetitem =ui->listWidget->item(i);
 _qlistwidgetitem->setText(list.at(i).baseName());
  }
```

Comment: Your code seems ok - except that you don't need to `QListWidgetItem *_qlistwidgetitem =ui->listWidget->item(i);`, because as I understand it this should be the same as `qlistwidgetitem`, so you could simply `qlistwidgetitem->setText(list.at(i).baseName())`.

Comment: Why do you think you need a better or faster way? Do you experience performance problems?

Comment: It 's working fine ,but didnt now if this is proper way to do ti .